# Is it possible to use R in emacs similar to a term mode?

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I would like to work in ESS/R in emacs in a way similar to term mode. That is, I don't want the cursor move away from the command line when I try to copy some text from the R console. Also I would like to rebind the up arrow key to previous command.

Answer (score 3):

## Your way

The "previous" and "next" commands use respectively `comint-previous-input` and `comint-next-input` functions. They can be mapped to `up` and `down` arrow key:

```
(define-key comint-mode-map [up] 'comint-previous-input)
(define-key comint-mode-map [down] 'comint-next-input)
```

I am not aware of a solution to lock the cursor while a copy/paste.

If you really want a console behavior, maybe you should simply use a console as it will fit your wishes.

## Bonus: the default Emacs way

I do not use `R`, but I use `octave`, `clojure` and also `bash` in Emacs. All these repl ([Read–eval–print loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop)) behave the same way. For example, the arrow keys will simply move your cursor.

Here is a brief overview of my usage of a repl:

- `M->` will bring me to the bottom of the buffer
- `C-<up>` will cycle along previous commands
- `C-<down>` will cycle along next commands
- `C-r` `keywords` will search backward in the buffer. If the cursor is on a previous command, `<enter>` will re-execute the command
- for copy/paste I do not use the mouse, but `M-w` (copy) and `C-y` (paste) where the cursor is. `M-y` will replace your paste by previous copied entries.

Maybe, it changes your habits or shortcuts from other desktop applications. However, on the bright side, these repl behaves in a consistent way in Emacs. Each time you use a repl, these keys will do the job as intended.